# Initialize dictionary, loop through list, add words and increment counter in dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I've added an example to hopefully make this clearer. I'm trying to do the following: add words from sentence that aren't in words dict to a list, then take those words and add them to a dictionary 'new_words_dict'. Only add words once, no duplicates, and increment a counter to track how many times the word appears. For example, 'happy' would appear in the dictionary once with a counter of 2.

I'm able to create the list and add words to the dictionary, but I'm not incrementing the value in the dictionary correctly.

```
words = {'abandon':-2,'abandoned':-2,'abandons':-2,'abducted':-2,'abduction':-2,
'abductions':-2,'abhor': -3}
sentence = {'abandon', 'abandoned', 'abhorrent', 'hello', 'smart', 'hello', 'die',
'happy', 'sad', 'up', 'down', 'happy', 'smart','cool', 'clean', 'mean'}         

new_words_list = []                  #Empty list
new_words_dict = {}                  #Empty dict 

for word in sentence:
if word not in words:    
        new_words_list.append(word)  
print new_words_list        

for word in new_words_list:
    if word not in new_words_dict:
        new_words_dict[word] = {}
        new_words_dict[word] =1
else:
    if word in new_words_dict:
        new_words_dict[word] +=1              
print new_words_dict
```

This prints the new_words_dict, but the value counters don't increment correctly.

Comment: I see you're doing `for each` a few times. Shouldn't you be using those `each` values somewhere, though? Also, where is `tweetscore` defined?

Comment: It's a extremely incomplete code.

Comment: @Keving. Agreed, but I get an error when i incorporate it in the loop, like:new_terms[each]["neg_tweets"] += 1. Here's the dict i get:{0: {}, 'neg_tweets': 0, 'total_tweets': 4, 'pos_tweets': 0, u'online': {}}. Online is the word im struggling to pull out of the dict.

Comment: Why are you initiating a new dictionary for each term exactly? And what do you think is the second row of your code (new_terms[term] = {}) doing?

Comment: My intention here: (new_terms[term] = {})  is to add a new word to the dict, but i think i'm going wrong here. I'm going through a list and adding unique words to a dict and incrementing counters as i go. dict ouput should be new_terms {term,[pos_tweets,neg_tweets, total_tweets]}

Comment: But up there, in the second row, what kind of variable is "term"? Down in the loop I understand, but up there?
And in your "dict output", what's the key and what's the value?

Comment: @user2471446 pls show more code. And what is your input and what your desired output?

Comment: Understood, have updated the example, hopefully it's simpler to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this in a confusing and unnecessarily complicated way. [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) can do most of the work for you:

```
import collections

words = {'abandon':-2,'abandoned':-2,'abandons':-2,'abducted':-2,'abduction':-2,
'abductions':-2,'abhor': -3}
# throw away the values in the dictionary because they aren't being used
words = words.keys()  

# this is a list [] not a dictionary ()
sentence = ['abandon', 'abandoned', 'abhorrent', 'hello', 'smart', 'hello', 
    'die', 'happy', 'sad', 'up', 'down', 'happy', 'smart','cool',
    'clean', 'mean'] 


counts = collections.Counter([word for word in sentence if word not in words])

print counts 
Counter({'hello': 2, 'smart': 2, 'happy': 2, 'down': 1, 'die': 1, 'up': 1, 
'sad':1, 'abhorrent': 1, 'clean': 1, 'mean': 1, 'cool': 1})
```

It is possible that this is not what you *actually* want because your code is so broken. To the best of my understanding, it does do what your question asks for.

Comment: this is correct based on the question. thanks. question: i can almost get his result in code above, but counters don't increment properly, any clue why? i'd prefer sticking with that structure for now, thanks.

Comment: I cannot even understand the rough structure of your code. For example `if word not in words: new_words_list = []` empties `new_words_list` on every loop so that `new_words_list` can only ever have one element in it. If you meant that my code's counters were incorrect, I count 2 "hello" in `sentence` and 1 "abhorrent", and so on.

Comment: Understood, updated example. Your solution worked, but I'd like to stick with the structure I have. It's not as elegant, but good learning exercise for me. So, my goal is to add list items to dictionary as a key, and increment a counter for each occurrence they have in the list. I'm almost there, but the counter doesn't increment properly. That's where i was hoping to get some help.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Maybe it was just an indentation problem?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with msw, your code is unnecessarily complex. Nevertheless, since you want to stick with it and learn something from it, here's your code with a few comments and corrections:

```
# dictionary with weird values, but we're only counting keys anyway
words = {'abandon':-2,'abandoned':-2,'abandons':-2,'abducted':-2,'abduction':-2,
'abductions':-2,'abhor': -3}
# this is a list, not a dictionary!
sentence = ['abandon', 'abandoned', 'abhorrent', 'hello', 'smart', 'hello', 'die',
'happy', 'sad', 'up', 'down', 'happy', 'smart','cool', 'clean', 'mean']

# empty list to save words in
new_words_list = []
# empty dict to save words and counts in
new_words_dict = {}

# first loop finds new words and saves them in new_words_list
for word in sentence:
  if word not in words:    
    new_words_list.append(word)  
print new_words_list        

# second loop counts new words
for word in new_words_list:

  # if the word is not in the dictionary yet, add it as key with another
  # dictionary as value (which doesn't make sense). Then replace this empty
  # dictionary with a simple integer (1).
  if word not in new_words_dict:
    new_words_dict[word] = {}
    new_words_dict[word] = 1

  # this should be elif, I assume. Then it would increment the counter of the
  # word in new_words_dict by 1.
  elif word in new_words_dict:
    new_words_dict[word] += 1              
print new_words_dict
```

Please note that `new_words_dict[word] = {}` in the second loop doesn't make any sense, since you want a counter and not a dictionary.

By the way, I don't see any problems with the counter here. This might be because I corrected the indentation of your `else`/`elif` statement (I'm not sue if you only didn't indent it here or also in your original code?).